# parsing regular exprision date

Tags: java, android, regex, validation

I am trying to parse a string on java .
the type that I have is

```
EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss z
```

like

```
 Sat, 10 Mar 2012 20:01:27 +0200
```

or it can be without the space

```
 Sat,10 Mar 2012 20:01:27 +0200
```

and I want to get string like this

```
  kk:mm dd/MM/yyyy
```

thanks a lot!
can you give an example how to do it without formatdate only with regular expression

Comment: I did some examples but still dont know how to convert MMM to MM I think to start [a-zA-Z]+,[0-9]+ and so on but I dont thinks its right to do

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier with `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z");
Date date = formatter.parse("Sat, 10 Mar 2012 20:01:27 +0200");

SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm dd/MM/yyyy");
String output = formatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly write a regular expression to do this, but why not just use SimpleDateFormat.parse and SimpleDateFormat.format?

If you accept two different formats, you can do the first parse in a try/catch and in the catch block for ParseException, you can do the second check.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html